# How to create materialized view with Timescale by Liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, timescaledb

I'm trying to load sql file by Liquibase for creating materialized view with Timescale. When Liquibase try to load the sql query I got:

> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: CREATE
> MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA cannot run inside a transaction block
> [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW...]

I can load the query manually directly to database.

Comment: Try adding `runInTransaction="false"` as an attribute to your `changeSet`

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!